# pip, how to remove dead index base url

Tags: python, pip

When i try to install a package using pip it first tries to fetch from a url which no longer exists which leads to the following error

```
Cannot fetch index base URL http://xyz.xxx:8080/simple/
```

but it goes on to download and install the package from pypi.I want to get rid of this index base url, i don't want to see this message every time.I don't remember how i added this url but it was a valid private package index at some point.I've already gotten rid of the url from the /etc/hosts file but pip still tries to fetch packages from that location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like there is a pip configuration file where you've added the URL. Quote from [docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html):

> The names and locations of the configuration files vary slightly
>   across platforms.
>
> On Unix and Mac OS X the configuration file is: $HOME/.pip/pip.conf
>
> On Windows, the configuration file is: %HOME%\pip\pip.ini

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue for a long time and I solved finally using this metheod
There is a manual way to do this. First use

`pip config list`

This will show a list of configuration in pip.ini, specially 'global.extra-index-url'. If you see the url as value for this cofig, you can "unset" it using:

`pip config unset global.extra-index-url`

when you run this, a message will be shown in terminal: "Writing to ...\pip\pip.ini"
I suggest that also unset global.trusted_host related to this setting to be sure about other side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, solved it by using `unset` with `sudo`.

So in your example, if you run `pip config show`, you should see:

```
global.extra-index-url=http://xyz.xxx:8080/simple/
```

You can then remove it with:

```
sudo pip config --global unset global.extra-index-url
```

You can check `pip config show` again to ensure it's gone.